# Targeting a class in the from the View

Tags: ruby, api, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.

I am trying to access the class I created below and iterate through it in the View. The puts line in my Controller is working correctly and outputting the data so I know it is properly being set.

However, when I try to print the items in the View it gives me the following error:

NoMethodError in Actions#list
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

So obviously I am not targeting the class correctly. How should I be doing this? I have read several different questions / tutorials with no luck in implementation.

After following Mattherick's (further) instructions my code now looks like this:

Model:

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :value, :name, :type, :details, :available, :date, :id
#This calls and API which contains JSON data I am trying to display
def self.mylist
    mylist = folder_list('sub', 'tld', $myAuthID, path='/')
end

end
```

Controller:

```
class ListItemsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @list_item = ListItem.new
end

def index
    @list_item = ListItems.mylist
end
end
```

View:

```
<%= @list_items. each do |item| %>
<%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't check the mvc pattern? :)

You cannot iterate over your class, you can iterate over objects of your class

```
# app/models/list_item.rb
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :value, :name, :type, :details, :available, :date, :id

  # Update
  def self.mylist
    # your api call
  end

end

# app/controllers/list_items_controller.rb
class ListItemsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @list_item = ListItem.new
  end

  # Update
  def index
   @list_items = ListItem.mylist
  end

end

# app/views/list_items/new
<%= form_for @list_item do |f| %>
  <% # your form fields %>
<% end %>

# app/views/list_items/index
<%= @list_items. each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

More information about this basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And what do you want with your list-method?

**UPDATE:**

I updated the model and the index action of the controller.

Comment: mylist = folder_list('subdomain', 'tld', $myAuthID, path='/') 
calls an API that I have to parse the data from. Which is what I was doing in the list method. I was able to output that data to the console find but I cannot get it to the view.

Comment: Ah ok. Change your method to def self.mylist ...end in the model. And change in the index action the ListItem.all call to ListItem.mylist

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mattherick. I made the changes to match what you have. What I am not understanding is where do I parse the JSON data that is returned from the API call?

Comment: You have to do everything within your model method. In the controller just call the method an set the @variable for the view. Data manipulation should be in the model..MVC principle..

Comment: That's how I ended up doing it. Having to learn / use too many new principals and languages at the same time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@newList contains a single, new instance of ListItem. So you can't do the method `.each` on it.

If you want several objects in @newList you'd need to do

```
@newList = ListItem.all
```

in the controller method (better to put it in the `def index` method rather than `def new`)

If you want to just access the single object, then you'd be better off forgetting the each loop and doing...

```
<td><%= @newList.name %></td>
```

Comment: I changed it to .all and def index and still get the same error.